# How to use grep or sed to extract multiple matches in the same line

Tags: shell, sed, grep, regular-expression

I have a file that, amongst other things, has text like this:

```
<TR><TD>5</TD><TD>Ukraine</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>3</TD><TD>Vietnam</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>3</TD><TD>Taiwan</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>3</TD><TD>Netherlands</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>3</TD><TD>South Korea</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>3</TD><TD>Great Britain</TD></TR>
```

I want to only extract the information between the `<TD>` elements:

```
5 Ukraine
3 Vietnam
3 Taiwan
3 Netherlands
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this

```
$awk -F"[>|<]" '{print $5,$9}' input.txt
5 Ukraine
3 Vietnam
3 Taiwan
3 Netherlands
3 South Korea
3 Great Britain
```

using sed commnad

```
$ sed "s#<TR><TD>\(.\)</TD><TD>\(.*\)</TD></TR>#\1 \2#" input.txt
5 Ukraine
3 Vietnam
3 Taiwan
3 Netherlands
3 South Korea
3 Great Britain
```

Comment: Why `awk -F"[>|<]"` instead of `awk -F"[><]"`?

Comment: yes.. you can use without pipe..

Comment: I was just curious, you gave a good answer!

Comment: `[>|<]` is incorrect as it will allow `|` as a delimiter. Use `[><]` or `(>|<)`. In any case, this strategy will be very brittle and should probably not be generalized. Use a proper parser if you are not 100% positive the data has a consistent & predictable format.